# Conditional Where clause in SQL query if one or both date range parameters are null

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure if I am asking the right question here, but I will try to explain what I need. I need to write a SQL query with a `@StartDate` and an `@EndDate` parameter.

If both parameters have a value, then my `where` clause will need to include:

```
WHERE CAST(CreatedDate AS date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

If `@EndDate` is null, then it should be:

```
WHERE CAST(CreatedDate AS date) = @StartDate
```

If both or null then the date should not be a part of the WHERE clause at all.

I have tried a couple of things like:

```
DECLARE @StartDate varchar(20) = '12-02-2020'
DECLARE @EndDate varchar(20) = ''

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Support_Requests]
WHERE 
    CAST(CreatedDate AS date) >= ISNULL(@StartDate, CreatedDate)
    AND CAST(CreatedDate AS date) <= ISNULL(@EndDate, CreatedDate)
```

and also:

```
DECLARE @StartDate varchar(20) = '12-02-2020'
DECLARE @EndDate varchar(20) = ''

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Support_Requests]
WHERE (@EndDate IS NULL 
       AND (CAST(CreatedDate AS date) >= @StartDate) 
            OR (@EndDate IS NOT NULL 
                AND CAST(CreatedDate AS date) >= @StartDate 
                AND CAST(CreatedDate AS date) <= @EndDate))
```

I am hoping there is a way to do this without the need for dynamic SQL. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cast your column, it'll be bad for performance. I also *assume* that your parameters are `date` data types, but that your column is actually a date and time (such as a `datetime2`), due to your casting. You can then just use a single `ISNULL` on the parameters, and then an `OR` for when they are both `NULL`:

```sql
WHERE (CreateDate >= @StartDate AND CreateDate < DATEADD(DAY,1,ISNULL(@EndDate,@StartDate))
   OR (@StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL)
```

You'll probably want to put an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` in there too, as the plan for when they both have `NULL` could be very different to when they don't.

Answer (score 3):

Your first variant was quite close. Rather than using the proprietary `ISNULL`, we can use the SQL standard [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead. Which supports more than two arguments:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime2 = '20200212'
Declare @EndDate datetime2 = null

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Support_Requests]
WHERE 
    cast(CreatedDate as date) >= COALESCE(@StartDate, CreatedDate)
    AND cast(CreatedDate as date) <= COALESCE(@EndDate, @StartDate, CreatedDate)
```

Logically, if `@EndDate` is null and `@StartDate` is not, this effectively becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Support_Requests]
WHERE 
    cast(CreatedDate as date) >= @StartDate
    AND cast(CreatedDate as date) <= @StartDate
```

Which will only be true if `CreatedDate` is equal to `@StartDate`.

I am slightly concerned by the casts - if they're there because the type of `CreatedDate` isn't `date`, I'd strongly suggest that the table definition by updated. If, on the other hand, they're being used to "cast away" a time component, then the same operation should also be being done on the right hand side, inside the `COALESCE`, so that the values compare equal.